# what is the use of @autowired annotation in Spring.What is meant by the term autowired

Tags: java, spring

I checked many tutorials but could not find a satisfactory answer.Does this annotation is performing Dependency injection of the properties.I have heard that this can be applied to a method,constructor or field but for what purpose.

Comment: @Jack: This is not a duplicate, the focus of both questions differs a lot.

Comment: I would recommend using the @Inject annotation going forward.

Comment: It's a very broad subject. Don't check tutorials to get the whole picture. Check the spring reference. More specifically the section on [`@Autowired`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@Autowired` annotation is performing Dependency Injection.

If `@Autowired` is applied to

- a field: then the dependency is stored in this field
- a setter: then the setter is invoked, with the parameter that is determined by the same algorithm like for the field dependency injection
- a constructor: then the constructor is invoked with the parameters determined by the same algorithm like for the field dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

We use @Autowired for :

a. Less abstraction in the system .

b. When Spring finds an @Autowired annotation used with setter methods, it tries to perform byType autowiring on the method.

Comment: Refer to : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm for more i nfo